# asp.net 4 get values from connection string

Tags: asp.net

I have a SQL connection string being stored in the web.config.

How can I pull items like server name, username, password... inside of C# ASP.Net code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder_members.aspx) for that:

```
var connectionString = GetConnectionString(); //e.g. use code shown in other answer
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);

var user = builder.UserID;
```

There's some sample code on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("name of connection string in web.config")

[Here is a link to the msdn documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Use a Regular Expression or the [DbConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder.connectionstring.aspx) class in the BCL.