# asp.net and connection string item values

Tags: asp.net

i have a SQL connection in my web.config.

i know how to get it in my .net code but how do i pull out the actual values inside teh connection string like the username, password, and server name?!?!?!?

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp.net 4 get values from connection string ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756070/asp-net-4-get-values-from-connection-string)

Comment: don't post the same question multiple times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder_members.aspx) for that:

```
var connectionString = GetConnectionString(); //e.g. use code shown in other answer
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);

var user = builder.UserID;
```

There's some sample code on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
            string[] arr = ConnectionString.Split(";".ToCharArray());
            string server = null, database = null, userid = null, password = null;

            foreach (string t in arr)
            {
                if (t.StartsWith("Data Source="))
                {
                    server = t.Substring(t.LastIndexOf("=") + 1);
                }
                else if (t.StartsWith("DATABASE="))
                {
                    database = t.Substring(t.LastIndexOf("=") + 1);
                }
                else if (t.StartsWith("User ID="))
                {
                    userid = t.Substring(t.LastIndexOf("=") + 1);
                }
                else if (t.StartsWith("Password="))
                {
                    password = t.Substring(t.LastIndexOf("=") + 1);
                }
            }
```

Above code should work.